# copy and paste function in excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

When I copy and paste a range of cells (these cells have white and other coloured backround colors) into a new area, I get a grey background over the entire pasted area. Why is this? Is it a setting? How do I get the background colours back in the newly pasted area. Please help

Comment: Hi, by default Excel pastes everything, or you can choose from the context menu to paste selectively (just values, just format etc). As it seems to be something unusual, please edit your question to add screenshots of what you're copying and what the pasted result looks like. What version of Excel?

Comment: Did you use conditional formatting to color cells?

Comment: No, just the standard paste button, which is the far left paste button when doing this

Comment: Reg, I will send a screen shot of the worksheet on Friday

Comment: hi Reg how do copy and paste to show how it exactly looks in my spreadsheet or how do I send an attachment of the file to show you

Comment: Reg it is excel  from office2019